# Need help identifying the military service and rank

Tags: world-war-one, identification, uniform

Thinking WW1.  Photos in box of family stuff.

[image]

Comment: Also, the single bar on the epaulet makes him a first or second lieutenant, but since we can't tell what color it is, it's unlikely you'll ever know which.

Answer (score 9):

Typical World War II era US Army uniform, this an [Army Air Force](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/coat-service-type-m1940-united-states-army-air-forces-gen-hap-arnold/nasm_A19610010000) example as evidenced by the winged propeller branch insignia on the lapels.  Rank shown is a Lieutenant, probably 2d Lieutenant.  Wings on left breast are officer crew type, not pilot wings; they look like [Bombardier wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_Badge).  Absence of decorations, even of the [American Campaign Ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Campaign_Medal#Criteria), awarded for service within the continental limits of the United States for an aggregate period of 1 year, would indicate that this is a graduation type photo after completion of advanced training.  Probably entered service after 7 Dec 1941 as, likewise above, there is no ribbon signifying award of the [American Defense Service Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Defense_Service_Medal) which was awarded to personnel who had service from the beginnings of the war in Europe up to the Japanese attack on Pearl Harbor.